# Best practice for exception logging in tiered application to avoid duplicate error log messages

Tags: java, exception, logging, n-tier-architecture

In a classic 3 tiered application with a presentation tier, service tier and dao tier what is most appropriate way to ensure concise and unduplicated exception reporting log messages. Imagine your dao layer catches any type of checked exception (we'll use Java terminology but same concept applicable to other exception handling languages) and translates that into a daoexception with an appropriate message. Should the appropriate message (eg. "Exception occurred while accessing db" + e.getMessage()) also be logged at the same time in dao layer? Then the service layer catches all daoexceptions, itself provides an appropriate service layer message, translating the daoexception (wrapping it) into a serviceexception and then rethrows. Should the service layer also log the caught exception? In short:

- Should just the dao layer log it?
- Should just the service layer log it?
- Should both tiers log it?
- Or should each situation be considered on a
  case by case basis according to usecase / service call etc?

I'm ignoring the presentation tier for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace in the service layser exception will contain the underlying dao exception, So I guess it makes sense just to log it at the servicelayer.

Comment: Thanks for response Sajit. Your point of view certainly seems valid.

Answer (score 0):

The question is subjective to me. AFAIK Its a decision made by the design.

To answer, shouldnt you be considering the requirement to log the calls and exceptions, some you log, some you eat, some you ignore. And for webservices or other component invocations, you certainly would need a service layer logging. I would rather go with 4th option in your question.

Comment: try not to ask subjective questions in stackoverflow forums but I guess I must concede here that perhaps there is no universally correct answer. Still if people are happy to vote on an answer it would informative to get consensus on what majority of people choose.

Answer (score 0):

I will log at the highest possible level.

Do you happen to use any `Commons` libraries from Apache, for example you may come across `StringUtils.isBlank()`. These libraries would not log any error messages within, instead, if they need to, they will throw the exception back to you, where you decide to handle it, or print any helpful debug messages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chin. I certainly get your point of view. And many popular APIs appear to follow your example of letting the calling client deal with the issue. Since our Dao already lives in the application, I am less certain the comparison here is as clear cut. Logging at the highest level is one way to avoid duplicating the exception trace in log file. But do you lose some control over granularity of logging - for instance, in some cases you want log.warn, in others log.error, or even log.info. By uniformly applying, I can see it being harder to distinguish between causes etc.

Comment: Please allow me to hear more opinions before marking your answer as the correct one.

Comment: I agree with your answer in general but your example of [`StringUtils.isBlank`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank\(java.lang.String\)) is confusing since that method doesn't seem to throw any exceptions. Can you clarify?